# Remove the last slug from URL in 301 redirect with regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Hope you guys can help. I'm facing the brick wall right now

What I want is this:

This URL should remove the last slug in URL (the month)
And then rewrite "event" to "vare"

`https://domain.dk/event/svampetur-roskilde/2023-08-26/`

to this

`https://domain.dk/vare/svampetur-roskilde/`

I can easy go and do this "event" to "vare" with this redirect.

```
# 301 --- ^/event/* => /vare/
RewriteRule ^\^/event/\*$ /vare/? [L,R=301]
```

But this is not removing the last path with dates.

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Comment: _"with this redirect"_ - that is not actual code that would perform any redirect, but just parts of it. So we don't know right now what directive you actually used. Please show the actual code you used, not just fragments of it.

Comment: Ohh my bad. It's because I just use Wordpress Redirection for this test, because I was to lazy to do it direct in htaccess. 

The actual code i'm using is here:

# 301 --- ^/event/* => /vare/
RewriteRule ^\^/event/\*$ /vare/? [L,R=301]

Comment: `^\^/event/\*$` should not match your input URL to begin with. No idea what you tried to achieve with `^\^` at the start there.

Comment: "last slug in URL (the month)" - Should read "last _path-segment_ (the date, `YYYY-MM-DD`)". The "slug" could be anything, but often refers to a _title_.

Answer (score 1):

I asked ChatGPT because it was hard for me to explain what I want here.
This is what it came up with from the 4. answer.

[image]

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^event/(.+)/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/?$ /vare/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Since you appear to be using this on a WordPress site, you need to make sure this rule goes at the **top** of the `.htaccess` file (before the WordPress code block).

Comment: Yes of cause. Every 301 redirect suppose to be in the top of the file. Thanks :)

Comment: Please note that posting ChatGPT-generated content is [currently banned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073).